# How to make FunSuite test stop from exiting when a Timer has active scheduled Task

Tags: java, scala, timer, scalatest

Take this class:

```
import java.util.Timer
import java.util.TimerTask
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock

class TimerClass{
  var timer: Timer = new Timer()
  var queue:Seq[Int] = Seq[Int]()
  val lock: ReentrantLock = new ReentrantLock()

  def task():TimerTask = {
    new TimerTask {
      def run () = {
        lock.lockInterruptibly()
        try {
          println(s"running task!")
          println(queue)
          queue = Seq[Int]()
        }
        finally {
          lock.unlock()
        }
      }
    }
  }

  def activate(): Unit = {
    lock.lockInterruptibly()
    try {
      println("activated")
      //reset timer and reschedule task
      timer.cancel()
      queue = queue :+ 1
      timer = new Timer()
      timer.schedule(task(), 1000L)
    } finally{
      lock.unlock()
    }
  }
}
```

And when tested in FunSuite as such:

```
  test("timer test"){
    val timeclass = new TimerClass()
    timeclass.activate()
    timeclass.activate()
    timeclass.activate()
  }
```

The test runs and prints activated three times, one line for each time the activate function is called, however the test exits before the TimerTask is ran. I expected the test to wait until the Timer's threads finished running. What am I missing? I also tried running as daemon but that didn't fix it. I think futures might work here but I dont know how to go about that.

Comment: @TomerShetah I read [here](https://www.iitk.ac.in/esc101/05Aug/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html) that programs 'By default, a program keeps running as long as its timer threads are running. ' Of course I assumed that was true but it may not be. Using a Thread.sleep(1000L) makes the program wait and the task finishes, a work around.

Comment: I have just tried to reproduce it, and it seems to wait for this thread. Why do you think it exited? I increased the time of waiting to 10 seconds and I still see it is printed.

Comment: @TomerShetah When I ran it the test exited before the task printed "running task!". So you tried it out and had the wait on the timer for 10 seconds and got it to print running task?

Comment: Yes. I've got printed both `running task!` and the queue content.